# How to call a service .srv from Terminal

Tags: ros, call-service, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A short question:

I have a service defined like this: (**navigate.srv**)

```
string[] path
---
bool command_processed
```

I would like to call it by a terminal with a command like:

```
rosservice call /navigate ...
```

I have tried with: 
... "path1, path2, path3" 
... 'path1, path2, path3' 
... "path1", "path2", "path3" 
... 'path1', 'path2', 'path3' 
... path1 path2 path3 
... path1, path2, path3 
... 
But i don't find the correct text chain(argument) to the service works.
Could someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131796/how-to-call-a-service-.srv-from-terminal/) by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 375 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-21**:
It's a list, so something along '{path: []}. 'Can you try the "cheater" way and try tab completion?

**Comment by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on 2014-02-24**:
Thank you very much. The "cheater" way was the solution. I had underestimated the power of tab ;)

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.ros.org/users/59901/m.bahno/) on 2020-10-09**:
The tab completion is in this case surprisingly helpful! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the this help: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine?

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-23**:
I know that this is an old thread, but this is helpful too: http://wiki.ros.org/rosservice